# Cannot Access Java Class Exception - Access Specifier Limitation

Tags: java

```
# EvenDriver.java
package com.EventDrivenScenario.SystemElements;

import com.EventDrivenScenario.Exceptions.TableFullException;
import java.util.Random;

public class Table {
     static final int TABLE_SIZE = 6;
     static int tableCurrentSize;
     Table(){
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
          Random eventTrigger = new Random();
          while(true){
               try {
                   if(eventTrigger.nextLong()%2 == 0){
                        new HumanBeing();
                   }
                   if (tableCurrentSize == TABLE_SIZE) {
                       throw new TableFullException();
                   }
               } catch(TableFullException e) {
                      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                      break;
               }
         }
     }
}

class HumanBeing{
    HumanBeing(){
         new Chairs();
    }
}

class Chairs{
     Chairs(){
         Table.tableCurrentSize++;
     }
}
# TableFullException
package com.EventDrivenScenario.Exceptions;
public class TableFullException extends Exception{
    TableFullException(){

    }
    public String getMessage() {
         return ("Table Full - No More Visitors");
    }
}
```

In the above code when i try to compile #EventDriver.java, I am getting compile time error indicating that TableFullException is not public and cannot be accessed outside package in spite of declaring it as public.

but if I change the package statement in both files to ##package com.EventDriver;## It works fine. I just want to understand why the above code throwing compile time error in spite of provide public access specifier for TableFullException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TableFullException` constructor is not public, so you can't create an instance of that exception from a class that doesn't belong to the same package. Make the constructor public, and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a package private constructor for the class. 
You have defined a constructor as package private by not giving any access modifier to the constructor Example :

```
public class PackagePrivateClassConstructor{
     PackagePrivateClassConstructor(){}
}
```

You can use this constructor in the same package but outside the package it won't allow you to use it.

**This is true for all you class Table,Chairs & HumanBeing.**

You need to change it to

```
public class MyClass{
     public MyCLass(){}
}
```